# Segmentation fault in an attempt to implement a binary tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

I am trying to implement a binary tree structure in C++.
I want a tree with '8' depth i.e. I want an attribute_struct with 1 attribute_node and 2 pointers to other 2 attribute_struct to make a binary tree.
Here is the data structure and its creation method that I defined :

```
struct person{
    public :
        char name[20];
};

struct attribute_node{
    int attribute;
    person * child_person;
};
struct attribute_struct{
    attribute_node head_node;
    attribute_struct * yes_node;
    attribute_struct * no_node;
};

attribute_struct initialize_struct(attribute_struct initial_struct, int prop){
    if(prop < 8){
        attribute_struct new_yes_struct, new_no_struct;

        attribute_node temp_yes_node, temp_no_node;
        temp_yes_node.attribute = prop;
        temp_yes_node.child_person = NULL;
        temp_no_node.attribute = prop;
        temp_no_node.child_person = NULL;
        new_yes_struct.head_node = temp_yes_node;
        new_no_struct.head_node = temp_no_node;
        new_yes_struct.yes_node = NULL;
        new_no_struct.yes_node = NULL;
        new_yes_struct.no_node = NULL;
        new_no_struct.no_node = NULL;

        attribute_struct temp_yes_struct = initialize_struct(new_yes_struct, prop+1), temp_no_struct = initialize_struct(new_no_struct, prop+1);
        initial_struct.yes_node = &temp_yes_struct;
        initial_struct.no_node = &temp_no_struct;
        return initial_struct;
    }else{
        person temp_person;
        strcpy(temp_person.name, "temp");
        initial_struct.head_node.child_person = &temp_person;

        return initial_struct;
    }
}
attribute_struct create_initial_attribute_structure(){
    attribute_struct main_structure;
    attribute_node temp_node;
    temp_node.attribute = 3;
    temp_node.child_person = NULL;
    main_structure.head_node = temp_node;
    main_structure.yes_node = NULL;
    main_structure.no_node = NULL;
    main_structure = initialize_struct(main_structure, 1);
    return main_structure;
}
```

Well, I am getting a segmentation fault when I try to use  the structure as below.

```
int main(){
    attribute_struct main_struct = create_initial_attribute_structure();
    attribute_struct * current_head;
    current_head = &main_struct;
    int iter = 0;
    while(iter < 7){
        current_head = (*current_head).yes_node;
        cout << iter << endl;
        iter++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I cant determine whether the data structure is created wrong or if I am referencing it the wrong way. I used gdb but as its in the main function with no parameters I am not able to deduce anything.

Well the seg fault is after printing iter 2.
So, how can I determine whether the attibute_struct defined is correct and with 8 level of depth or whether I am referencing a NULL object?
Using if(current_head == NULL) cout << "Error"; inside the while loop does not help.

Comment: _I used gdb but as its in the main function with no parameters I am not able to deduce anything._   where does gdb indicate you are in code at the time of the crash? Looking at the variables in use, which (pointer) appears invalid and how could it have got that way?

Comment: Hello. Questions in Stackoverflow always seem a little nicer, if you actually put a question into them - not just describe a problem.

Comment: Backtrace gives me this -
#0  0x0000000000400bc2 in ?? ()

#1  0x0000000000000003 in ?? ()

#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Comment: this is C++ we use `nullptr` not `NULL` because `NULL` is defined to be 0 not `(void*)0` like it is in C, as such it may cause odd behavior on function overloads. Also you have a whole heap of RAII issues here... try fixing them first.

Comment: Not a single `malloc` or `pointers` returned seen anywhere... how exactly do you plan to build a tree ??? Use a simple C/C++ tutorial and start all over.. I think there are too many thing to fix

Comment: @Deepthought you don't actually need to use `malloc` for this (which would be a bad answer in C++ anyway as we have `new`) if you need dynamic allocation you can just use `std::vector`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `create_initial_attribute_structure` which sets `yes_node` to NULL

Then you set `current_head` to `yes_node` which is NULL

Then next iteration you derefference `current_head`

You are derefferencing NULL